# External Login throws 404 in Mono MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, owin

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 on top of Mono and it seems that Owin OAuth throws 404 for the virtual paths (in my case, both `/signin-facebook` and `/signin-google`. I'm using Xamarin and Mono on my Mac. I tried to run the same code in Visual Studio inside a virtual machine and it works properly. As much as possible, I don't want to resort to using Windows. (Mac is my designated work machine so moving to a PC will not work)

Anyone experienced the same error? Any lead to where to start looking will be very much appreciated.

Update (attached a screenshot):
[image: 404 Screenshot]